# Swift 4 - Google Places API filtering

Tags: swift, swift4, google-location-services

I am working in a swift 4 project with google places api. While entering my desired location’s search in the search bar, I need the google api to return only abbreviated form of states instead of displaying it fully. Example., Milford, CT, USA and not Milford, Connecticut, USA and similarly for all the other locations. I have attached the bit of code. Can anyone help me out here. All your inputs are welcomed. Thanks in advance!

```swift
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()

           filter.type = .city

            filter.country = "uk|country:fr|country:us"


            placesClient.autocompleteQuery(searchText, bounds: nil, filter: filter, callback: {(results, error) -> Void in

                if let _ = error {

                    autocompletionFailure?()

                }

                if let results = results {

                    //Filtering the results for given countries, so that only relevant data should be displayed.

                    let filteredItems = results.filter { (LocalisationHelper.containsString(apiValue: $0.attributedSecondaryText?.string.lowercased() ?? "", localValue:Constants.SearchCountriesName.guam)) || (LocalisationHelper.containsString(apiValue: $0.attributedSecondaryText?.string.lowercased() ?? "", localValue:Constants.SearchCountriesName.canada)) || (LocalisationHelper.containsString(apiValue: $0.attributedSecondaryText?.string.lowercased() ?? "", localValue:Constants.SearchCountriesName.usa) ) || (LocalisationHelper.containsString(apiValue: $0.attributedSecondaryText?.string.lowercased() ?? "", localValue:Constants.SearchCountriesName.unitedStates))  || (LocalisationHelper.containsString(apiValue: $0.attributedSecondaryText?.string.lowercased() ?? "", localValue:Constants.SearchCountriesName.puertoRico)) || (LocalisationHelper.containsString(apiValue: $0.attributedSecondaryText?.string.lowercased() ?? "", localValue:Constants.SearchCountriesName.northernMarianaIslands)) || (LocalisationHelper.containsString(apiValue: $0.attributedSecondaryText?.string.lowercased() ?? "", localValue:Constants.SearchCountriesName.virginIslands))}


                    self._searchResults.value = filteredItems

                    print("filters: \(filteredItems)")

                    searchCompleter?()

                }
```

Comment: Your result is a type GMSPlace, correct? It should contain a property GMSAddressComponent which has a .shortname version.

Comment: Hi @MichaelWells, Thanks for your input!. Where exactly can i use this in my code?

Comment: Your result should have a .placeID I thought it was already a GMSPlace but after reading the documentation I now realize it is actually a GMSAutocompletePrediction , the explanation on how to get a GMSPlace where you can access the above is listed here: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-id

Comment: honestly it might just be easier to create a dictionary with the 50 states and just reformat each string with a function or something if all you are trying to do is abbreviate each state.